# Folium can not call the "CircleMaker" feature

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, folium

I'm experimenting with jupyter notebooks and python. Geo/wifi plotting map (hopefully)

I'm a self taught novice so pretty sure my issue is with my ability to read and write...

SAMPLE OF MY DB HEADER:

```
MAC SSID    AuthMode    FirstSeen   Channel RSSI    CurrentLatitude CurrentLongitude    AltitudeMeters  AccuracyMeters  Type
```

MYSCRIPT:

```
mymap = folium.Map( location=[ df.CurrentLatitude.mean(), df.CurrentLongitude.mean() ], zoom_start=12)
for coord in df[['CurrentLatitude','CurrentLongitude','SSID','Type','MAC']].values:
    if (coord[3] == 'WIFI'):
        folium.CircleMaker(location=[coord[0],coord[1]], radius=1,color='red', popup=["SSID:", coord[2], "BSSID:", coord[4]]).add_to(mymap)
mymap.save('test_one.html') # saves to html file for display below
```

ATTEMPTED:

1. I've tried replacing the call function as "folium.feature.CircleMaker" which I think might have been the case if I was using an older version of folium.
2. updated folium with pip, running current version.

ERROR:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
    /tmp/ipykernel_3702/3885511742.py in <module>
          2 for coord in df[['CurrentLatitude','CurrentLongitude','SSID','Type','MAC']].values:
          3     if (coord[3] == 'WIFI'):
    ----> 4         folium.CircleMaker(location=[coord[0],coord[1]], radius=1,color='red', 
    popup=["SSID:", coord[2], "BSSID:", coord[4]]).add_to(mymap)
          5 mymap.save('test_one.html') # saves to html file for display below

                   AttributeError: module 'folium' has no attribute 'CircleMaker'
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably meant `folium.CircleMarker`. It's just a typo, the question should be closed.

Comment: Triple checking my spelling. I don't see where I miss spelled folium.CircleMaker

Comment: It is marker, not maker. You missed the 'r'. It happens to the best of us.

Comment: If this fixed your issue, please consider accepting the answer by clicking on the check mark on the left side of it.